# How to implement a registration activity in android that works only for once?

Tags: android, android-activity, registration

I'm designing an application that has an activity for registration process, this activity launches on default. I want this activity to be disabled forever once the registration process has been completed successfully and then it should be replaced by a different activity as the default activity for the rest of the lifetime of the application.I've tried to search my way through this problem but I've hardly found anything.Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once registration is complete, commit some value to the SharedPreferences, then in your splash screen or some other opening Activity, check the preferences. If the value indicates that the registration is complete, start a different Activity instead of the Registration one...

Example:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean regComplete = prefs.getBoolean("registration", false);
    if(regComplete) {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class));
    } else {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Registration.class));

   }
}
```

Better still:

Always launch the registration, but in `onCreate()`, simply launch a different Activity immediately and `finish()` the registration `Activity` if the prefs indicate that registration is complete.

**Edit**
SharedPreferences explained:

SharedPreferences lets you persist primitive values in your app. You grab the SharedPreferences by doing:

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

then you write to SharedPreferences by getting the Editor. To do this, you call

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.Edit();
```

then you can commit values to the editor by using key/values:

```
editor.putBoolean("some string as a key here", true/false);
```

Then to actually save that, you call `editor.commit();`

Then you grab values back from SharedPreferences by simply calling

```
prefs.getBoolean("some previously chosen string as a key here", true/false);
```

where true/false is the **default** value that will be returned if no such key exists...

This is convenient and lets you do simple things like:

```
    editor.putInt("some important number", 55);
    editor.commit();
```

......later

```
int i =  prefs.getInt("some important number", -1); 

if(i != -1) {
//do stuff
} else {
//do other stuff
}
```

Also, please see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: are the prefs values application persistent?

Comment: I will be humbled if you can make the code a bit mode detail, I have little or no experience of working with sharedprefrences.

Comment: okay so what I essentially need to do is to assign a value to the sharedprefrences object when the registration is done and use this value as the reference for registration. Got it.Thank you @LuxuryMode

Comment: Done, will use this idea...:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the registration Activity be the default.  Instead have another Activity as the default, and then at runtime it can check to see which Activity it should send the user to.  If they haven't registered then startIntent( RegistrationActivity.class ).

Comment: I like the idea I will give it a try.